# error C4335 when compile C++ project VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I have a C project that i am able to compile and run successfully, however when i add another include like `#include <vector>` even without actually using the vector type i am getting the following annoying errors:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio11.0\vc\include\wchar.h : error C4335: Mac file format detected: please convert the source file to either DOS or UNIX format
```

and around 30 more errors related to the same `wchar.h` file.

I have search for a solution and i have done the suggestion to save my project files with the windows end-of-line but that didn't help.

My goal in including the vector lib is to uses vectors in my current project.

EDIT:

I tried to open the `wchar.h` file using text editor but all i get is a blob of data nothing like an header file, maybe it is corrupted somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour You have to pay attention to the file i am getting these error `wchar.h` which is a file that i never touch. It seems that at the question there he has problems with its own project files.

Comment: The header `vector` is not available in C, only in C++. That said, if the file at the given path is really broken, you need to repair-install your compiler. Also, to rule out any errors in your code, create a simple C++ example application from scratch and include that header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After repairing the VS 2012 install it works as it should, i assume that the `wchar.h` file got corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Or open wchar.h in Notepad++ -> Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Windows format.
Here you can get Notepad++: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

If you don't have it, get it. It is a must have application on every programmers PC.

Answer (score 1):

The file wchar.h is not in the right encoding, probably it is Unicode or UTF8.

Open wchar.h from visual studio, select all and copy, create a new h file and past and save to replace the exsiting wchar.h